# How to delegate a subnet for Azure SQL Managed Instance in Pulumi C#

Tags: azure, pulumi, azure-sql-managed-instance

The Pulumi doc [Create subnet with a delegation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/network/subnet/#create-subnet-with-a-delegation) is wrong (it did not set `SubnetArgs.Delegations` property).

I tried to delegate subnet with following code:

```cs
//
// Managed Insatnce subnet must be delegated
//
var spokeManagedInstanceSubnet = new Subnet($"{SpokeVirtualNetwork}.{ManagedInstanceSubnet}", new AzureNative.Network.SubnetArgs {
    SubnetName = ManagedInstanceSubnet,
    AddressPrefix = spokeSubnetCidrs[ManagedInstanceSubnet],
    VirtualNetworkName = spokeVnet.Name,
    ResourceGroupName = mainResourceGroup.Name,
    Delegations = new InputList<DelegationArgs> { new DelegationArgs {
            ServiceName = "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances",
            Type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/delegations"
        }
    }
}, new CustomResourceOptions { DependsOn = { spokeVnet } });
```

But getting the following error:

> error: Code="InvalidRequestFormat" Message="Cannot parse the request." Details=[]

**How to delegate subnet for managed Instance ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is the `Name` input in the `DelegationArgs`. So it should look something like

```cs
var spokeManagedInstanceSubnet = new Subnet($"{SpokeVirtualNetwork}.{ManagedInstanceSubnet}", new AzureNative.Network.SubnetArgs {
    SubnetName = ManagedInstanceSubnet,
    AddressPrefix = spokeSubnetCidrs[ManagedInstanceSubnet],
    VirtualNetworkName = spokeVnet.Name,
    ResourceGroupName = mainResourceGroup.Name,
    Delegations = new InputList<DelegationArgs> { new DelegationArgs {
            ServiceName = "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances",
            Type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/delegations",
            Name = "" // name of delegation. Doesn't have to be the name of the managed instance
        }
    }
}, new CustomResourceOptions { DependsOn = { spokeVnet } });
```

I also think you don't need `Type` in there either.

When I say "think", I should say that I've not done this with C# and managed instances, but I've done similar with Typescript and container groups.

That looked something like this:

```js
const subnet = new network.Subnet(`subnet`, {
      resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
      virtualNetworkName: vnet.name,
      addressPrefix: "10.0.0.0/24",
      serviceEndpoints: [{
        service: "Microsoft.Sql"
      }],
      delegations: [{
        serviceName: "Microsoft.Containerinstance/containerGroups",
        name: `snet-delegation-containergroups`
      }]
    }, { parent: vnet });
```

Comment: `// name of managedinstance` -> managed instance is not created yet, so what exactly should `Name` value  be?

Comment: It is required to delegate the subnet first and then create managed instance in that delegated subnet

Comment: I've just updated my answer - it doesn't have to be the name of the managed instance. I got that wrong

Comment: Tried by setting `Name` & removing `Type` -> `error: update failed. Code="Failed" Message="The async operation failed."  `

Comment: Subnet delegation is working, `The async operation failed` might be related to managed instance. Do you have any hint on that?